# Google Vizualization with CSV data

Tags: api, csv, visualization, charts

I have a URL that returns data in CSV format.  I would like to use Google Vizualization to create an interactive chart of the data.  I've looked at several examples on Google Chart and Vizualization web page but I'm a bit confused as I'm not familiar with JavaScript or web programming in general.

Question: Do I have to use JavaScript to parse the CSV string myself and manually construct the DataTable with addColumn() and addRows()?  Or, is there a way to simply pass the CSV url to the charting function?  I'm hoping to do something like this:

```
var csv_data = get_data_from_url('http://...')
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(csv_data);
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, ...);
```

Can someone please help me out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it looks like they're using JSON or some close variant of JSON for the data.  You could try a CSV to JSON converter.  Apparently converting CSV to JSON is a fairly trivial operation, requiring only a few lines of code:

[converting CSV/XLS to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662859/convert-csv-xls-to-json)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I looked at the documentation on data sources:

http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/dev/implementing_data_source.html#responseformat

and it looks like the java.visualization.Query only takes JSON format....  I'm hesitant to use the CSV to JSON link because i don't want to expose the data to the outside.

Comment: Well, you could process it server side.  You can roll code any way you want with this; all of the examples I've seen only require about a dozen lines of code to perform the conversion.