# May I get a SQLite View on JSON format?

Tags: sqlite

I am using Firefox SQLIte plugin and I have an option to export as CSV. Is it possible to do it on JSON?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite is a [relational database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) and [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) is a natural textual representation of tabular data, as seen in the relational model. [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is a textual represenation of an *object*. As such, it's not really suited for the representation of tabular data.

That said, you can use the CSV file produced from the SQLite database to [generate JSON output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/662859/507519).

Comment: Considering tables can be thought of as a collection of records, and records a collection of labelled fields, I would think JSON is an excellent representational format.

Answer (score 1):

I used sqlite studio to convert result to json. It is open source it does a good job! Although you might need to massage the json data a bit because it contains things like DDL, etc.