# Format generated Excel using Apache POI JAVA

Tags: java, excel, apache

I found an example for generating excel file using apache poi. I have modified it to work with `List<Map<String, Object>>` but now i have problem with formatting the document. Hope some will know how to make it.

For now the document which is generated is good but it needs some formatting.

```
  public void generateReport(List<Map<String, Object>> metas, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request)
                throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

            String template = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/excel/template.xlsx");

            Workbook book = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(template));
            Sheet sheet = book.getSheetAt(0);

            CellStyle cellStyle = sheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();

            int interator = 0;
            int columnsNames = 0;
            int columnsLen = metas.get(0).size();

            Set<Object> keys = new LinkedHashSet<Object>();
            Map<String, Object[]> data = new TreeMap<String, Object[]>();
            String[] args = new String[columnsLen];

            response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=filename_.xlsx");

            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : metas.get(0).entrySet()) {
                keys.add(entry.getKey());
            }

            for (Map<String, Object> meta : metas) {

                if (columnsNames == 0) {
                    String[] colNames = keys.toArray(new String[metas.size()]);
                    data.put("0", colNames);
                }

                String[] keyLine = keys.toArray(new String[keys.size()]);

                for (int i = 0; i < metas.size(); i++) {
                    for (String s : keyLine) {
                        args[interator] = metas.get(i).get(s).toString();
                        interator++;
                    }

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.append("");
                    sb.append(i + 1);
                    String key = sb.toString();
                    data.put(key, args);

                    interator = 0;
                    args = new String[columnsLen];
                }

                Set<String> nKey = data.keySet();
                int rownum = 12;

                for (String kkey : nKey) {

                    Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
                    Object[] objArr = data.get(kkey);
                    int cellnum = 0;
                    for (Object obj : objArr) {
                        Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
                        if (obj instanceof String)
                            cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
                        else if (obj instanceof Integer)
                            cell.setCellValue((Integer) obj);
                    }
                }

            }

            HSSFRow row1 = (HSSFRow) book.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0);

            for (int i = 0; i < row1.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
                book.getSheetAt(0).autoSizeColumn(i);
            }

            Font font = book.getFontAt((short) 0);
            font.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);

            try {
                book.write(response.getOutputStream());
                book = new XSSFWorkbook();
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                e.getMessage();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.getMessage();
            }
        }
```

Comment: what kind of formatting?

Comment: I am trying to make all names of the columns bold. I also need all columns to have width to show all the content of every line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply bold text style for an entire row using Apache POI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286662/how-to-apply-bold-text-style-for-an-entire-row-using-apache-poi)