# JSON to xlsx converter

Tags: java, linux, json, excel

Is there a tool somewhere that already does this ?  I have seen this link:

[SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172158/converting-json-to-xls-csv-in-java)

But no relavent answer was given, there is also links, SO links and converters out there for xlsx to JSON, but have not found anything the other way around

An example conversion:

JSON:

```
{
"name" : "Joe",
"_id" : 7
}
```

Excel:

```
name  Joe
_id   7
```

'name' and 'joe' being in adjacent but separate cells\columns.

Comment: After reading that link, did you come up with how you wanted the json objects mapped to the spreadsheet cells? if so, you should include them in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know any generic API to do this work. But, if u already have a "mapper" for your json, you could generate the xls using the apache [POI API](http://poi.apache.org/) easily.

Comment: ah yes I forgot about this, I specifically see this:  http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I am closing this,I decided to use json all the time instead of trying to convert back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it very easy with [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql) console utility:

```
node alacon "select * into json('cities.json') from xlsx('cities.xlsx',{headers:true})"
```

To use Alasql console utility install [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) and then install [Alasql npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/alasql).