# Groovy code to convert json to CSV file

Tags: groovy

Does anyone have any sample Groovy code to convert a JSON document to CSV file? I have tried to search on Google but to no avail.

Example input (from comment):

```
[ company_id: '1',
  web_address: 'vodafone.com/',
  phone: '+44 11111',
  fax: '',
  email: '',
  addresses: [ 
      [ type: "office", 
        street_address: "Vodafone House, The Connection",
        zip_code: "RG14 2FN",
        geo: [ lat: 51.4145, lng: 1.318385 ] ]
  ],
  number_of_employees: 91272,
  naics: [
      primary: [ 
          "517210": "Wireless Telecommunications Carriers (except Satellite)" ],
      secondary: [ 
          "517110": "Wired Telecommunications Carriers",
          "517919": "Internet Service Providers",
          "518210": "Web Hosting"
      ]
  ]
```

More info from an edit:

```
def export(){
   def exportCsv = [ [ id:'1', color:'red', planet:'mars', description:'Mars, the "red" planet'], 
                     [ id:'2', color:'green', planet:'neptune', description:'Neptune, the "green" planet'],
                     [ id:'3', color:'blue', planet:'earth', description:'Earth, the "blue" planet'],
                   ]
    def out = new File('/home/mandeep/groovy/workspace/FirstGroovyProject/src/test.csv') 
    exportCsv.each {
        def row = [it.id, it.color, it.planet,it.description]
        out.append row.join(',')
        out.append '\n'
    }
    return out
}
```

Comment: This would be bespoke to your json as there is no specification that objects in a json array must contain the same properties.  Do you have some example json?  What have you tried?  What difficulty do you have?

Comment: i have String JSON data . i want to convert this json data to csv file using groovy code.
like here i have created csv file with static data but i want to create csv file from string json object and want to send this csv file as a attachment using send email code in groovy

Comment: Your question makes it apparent that you have some Json and want to make a CSV, but what JSON do you have?  Any solution is going to be unique to your json, as Json can take may forms, and doesn't have to match a csv format easily. Can you post some example Json into your question as an edit?

Comment: Map with the following structure (represented as Json):
[
company_id: '1'
web_address: 'http://vodafone.com/',
phone: '+44 11111',
fax: '',
email: '',
addresses: [
[
type: "office",
street_address: "Vodafone House, The Connection",
zip_code: "RG14 2FN",

geo: [
lat: 51.4145,
lng: 1.318385
]
]
],
number_of_employees: 91272,
naics: [
primary: [
"517210": "Wireless Telecommunications Carriers (except Satellite)",
],
secondary: [
"517110": "Wired Telecommunications Carriers",
"517919": "Internet Service Providers",
"518210": "Web Hosting"
]
],

Comment: Right, so I've added that formatted as an edit to your question. That's not a full list (it just ends), also what sort of format CSV were you expecting?

Comment: I think you should go complementing your question instead of using comments ... you can edit your question ...

Comment: def export(){
  def exportCsv = [
   [id:'1',color:'red',planet:'mars',description:'Mars, the "red" planet'],
   [id:'2',color:'green',planet:'neptune',description:'Neptune, the "green" planet'],
   [id:'3',color:'blue',planet:'earth',description:'Earth, the "blue" planet'],
  ]
  
  def out = new File('/home/mandeep/groovy/workspace/FirstGroovyProject/src/test.csv')
  exportCsv.each {
   def row = [it.id, it.color, it.planet,it.description]
   out.append row.join(',')
   out.append '\n'
  }
  return out

 }

Comment: here m using out as a csv file object to send file as attachment

Comment: All of this information should go in the question, and not in comments where it's impossible to read :-(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172158/converting-json-to-xls-csv-in-java
lets see here ..i want to implement this code in groovy

Answer (score 9):

Ok, how's this:

```
import groovy.json.*

// Added extra fields and types for testing    
def js = '''{"infile": [{"field1": 11,"field2": 12,                 "field3": 13},
                        {"field1": 21,             "field4": "dave","field3": 23},
                        {"field1": 31,"field2": 32,                 "field3": 33}]}'''


def data = new JsonSlurper().parseText( js ) 
def columns = data.infile*.keySet().flatten().unique()

// Wrap strings in double quotes, and remove nulls
def encode = { e -> e == null ? '' : e instanceof String ? /"$e"/ : "$e" }

// Print all the column names
println columns.collect { c -> encode( c ) }.join( ',' )

// Then create all the rows
println data.infile.collect { row ->
    // A row at a time
    columns.collect { colName -> encode( row[ colName ] ) }.join( ',' )
}.join( '\n' )
```

That prints:

```
"field3","field2","field1","field4"
13,12,11,
23,,21,"dave"
33,32,31,
```

Which looks correct to me

Comment: The script fails if a value contains a double quote, which would have to be escaped using two double quotes, for example `da"ve` should yield `"da""ve"`.

Comment: True... You should use a CSV library instead of the above