# Groovy collect from map and submap

Tags: json, csv, groovy, nested

I had a requirement to convert a JSON response into a csv file. I was able to successfully use Tim Yates' excellent code from here: [Groovy code to convert json to CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576162/groovy-code-to-convert-json-to-csv-file)

I now need to include the JSON's nested submap in the csv as well. The relationship between the map and submap is 1:1.

I've been unable to get the correct syntax for a collect statement that will retrieve both the parsed map and submap key/values.

Sample JSON

```
{items=
[
{ 
  created_at=2019-03-27
, entity_id=1
, extension_attributes=[]
},

{
  created_at=2019-03-27
, entity_id=2
, extension_attributes= { employee_id=Emp1, employee_type=CSR}//nested submap
}
]}
```

Groovy

```
import groovy.json.*

def data = new JsonSlurper().parseText( json ); //"json" is from GET request

def columns = ["created_at","entity_id","employee_id","employee_type"]

def encode = { e -> e ? /"$e"/ : "$e"}

requestFile.append( columns.collect { c -> encode( c ) }.join( ',' ) + '\n');

requestFile.append( data.items.collect { row ->columns.collect { colName -> encode( row[ colName ] ).replaceAll("null","") }.join( ',' )}.join( '\n' ) );//unsure how to use data.items.collect to fetch submap
```

I would like to either
1) Convert the JSON as follows to collect each key/value easily:

```
...
{
  created_at=2019-03-27
, entity_id=2
, employee_id=Emp1
, employee_type=CSR
}
...
```

or 2) Find out if there's a way to use Groovy's collect method to retrieve the map/submap as a flat map.

I am unfortunately not a programmer by trade, and any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the `flatten` closure which flattens an item recursively:

```
def flatten
flatten = { row ->
    def flattened = [:]
    row.each { k, v ->
        if (v instanceof Map) {
            flattened << flatten(v)
        } else {
            flattened[k] = v
        }
    }
    flattened
}
```

You should just replace `row` with `flatten(row)` at your last line so it looks like this:

```
requestFile.append(data.items.collect { row ->
    columns.collect {
        colName -> encode(flatten(row)[colName]).replaceAll("null", "")
    }.join(',')
}.join('\n'))
```

The result will be as follows:

```
"created_at","entity_id","employee_id","employee_type"

"2019-03-27","1",,
"2019-03-27","2","Emp1","CSR"
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitry! Was able to successfully test flatten closure and results were as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Also found that following allows for collect method to fetch nested elements:

```
def m = data.items.collect{[/"${it?.created_at?:''}"/,/"${it?.extension_attributes?.entity_id?:''}"/,/"${it?.extension_attributes?.employee_id?:''}"/,/"${it?.extension_attributes?.employee_type?:''}"/]}

m.each{requestFile.append(it.join(',')+'\n')}
```