# CSV generator does not support Array values for properties

Tags: java, csv, jackson, converters

I'm trying to develop an application that convert **JSON** to **CSV**.

I'm using **JACKSON** to parse **JSON** and write **CSV**.

Here is an **example** of a  **JSON** I'm trying to parse  :

```
{ "_id" : 0, 
 "name" : "aimee Zank", 
 "scores" : 
           [ 
             { "type" : "exam", "score" :   1.463179736705023 }, 
             { "type" : "quiz", "score" : 11.78273309957772 },  
             { "type" : "homework", "score" : 6.676176060654615 },  
             { "type" : "homework", "score" : 35.8740349954354 } 
            ] 
     }

  { "_id" : 1, 
    "name" : "Aurelia Menendez", 
    "scores" : 
              [ 
                { "type" : "exam", "score" : 60.06045071030959 }, 
                { "type" : "quiz", "score" : 52.79790691903873 }, 
                { "type" : "homework", "score" : 71.76133439165544 }, 
                { "type" : "homework", "score" : 34.85718117893772 } 
             ] 
       }

 { "_id" : 2, 
  "name" : "Corliss Zuk", 
   "scores" : 
             [ 
              { "type" : "exam", "score" : 67.03077096065002 }, 
              { "type" : "quiz", "score" : 6.301851677835235 }, 
              { "type" : "homework", "score" : 20.18160621941858 }, 
              { "type" : "homework", "score" : 66.28344683278382 } 
             ] 
         }
```

The two Java Classes :

JsonNode class

```
public class JsonNode {

private String _id;
private String name;
private Collection<ScoreType> scores;

/**
 * @return the _id
 */
public String get_id() {
    return _id;
}
/**
 * @param _id the _id to set
 */
public void set_id(String _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}
/**
 * @return the name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
/**
 * @param name the name to set
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
/**
  * @return the scores
 */
public Collection<ScoreType> getScores() {
    return scores;
}
/**
  * @param scores the scores to set
 */
public void setScores(Collection<ScoreType> scores) {
    this.scores = scores;
 }
 }
```

ScoreType class

```
public class ScoreType {
private String type;
private String score;
/**
 * @return the type
 */
public String getType() {
    return type;
}
/**
 * @param type the type to set
 */
public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}
/**
 * @return the score
 */
public String getScore() {
    return score;
}
/**
 * @param score the score to set
 */
public void setScore(String score) {
    this.score = score;
}

}
```

The method that  convert **JSON** to **CSV**

```
  ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();

    JsonNode jsonNode=mapper.readValue(new File("C:\\...\\...\\...\\test.json"), JsonNode.class);

    CsvMapper csvMapper=new CsvMapper();
    CsvSchema schema=csvMapper.schemaFor(JsonNode.class);

    schema=schema.withColumnSeparator(';');

    ObjectWriter myObjectWriter=csvMapper.writer(schema);

    FileOutputStream tempFileOutputStream=new FileOutputStream(out+"\\jsontocsv.csv");
    BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream=new BufferedOutputStream(tempFileOutputStream);
    OutputStreamWriter writerOutputStream=new OutputStreamWriter(bufferedOutputStream,"UTF-8");

    myObjectWriter.writeValue(writerOutputStream,jsonNode);
```

The console output :

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException: CSV generator does not support
```

Array values for properties

The CSV output :

```
"0";"aimee Zank";
```

That's what I have done so far.

So I'm facing two issues here :

1) The output CSV is not complete, it creates only one line and don't write scores.

2) The error in the console.

I'm using these **JACKSON** depandencies :

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Can anyone help me solving these issues ?

I hope I was clear enough.

**Edits** CSV I'm expecting :

```
_id;name;scores.type;scores.score;scores.type;scores.score;scores.type;scores.score
0;aimee Zank;exam;1.46;quiz;11.78;homework;6.67;homework;35.87
```

Ismail

Comment: Can you give an example how you want it in csv? i mean what a row in csv should look like

Comment: You are mixing 1.x and 2.x Jackson versions. Stick to 2.x.

Comment: @IsmailSen you have wrong library dependency. Refer to this page: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core

Comment: @AlexeyGavrilov I've corrected the maven depandecies. I only use `com.fasterxml.jackson.core`

Comment: @pratim_b I've added CSV output I want in the Edits

Answer (score 1):

Since a CSV is a tuple of simple values, it does indeed not support collections (JSON arrays) as column values. You have a `Collection<ScoreType>` as one of your bean's properties and this is causing your error.

Suggestion: add a `String` getter which turns your collection into a string, and build a CSV schema *manually* to avoid automatically using the Collection-valued column.

Comment: could you please details more yout suggestion

Comment: While CSV does not indeed have a native array/list type, Jackson does allow use of "in-cell" separators for logical arrays. Default separator is semicolon (character `;`), and as long as your property type is Java array or `Collection`, things should work with new enough Jackson CSV module version (at least 2.5 is needed I think).

Answer (score 0):

Try using custom json serializer for Collection attribute in JsonNode class and convert list to string.

```
public class JsonNode {

private String _id;
private String name;
@JsonSerialize(using=CollectionSerializer.class)
private Collection<ScoreType> scores;

}


public class CollectionSerializer extends StdSerializer<Collection<Object>> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected CollectionSerializer(Class<Collection<Object>> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    public CollectionSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Collection<Object> value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {

        gen.writeString(value.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(",")).toString());

    }

}
```