# How export json data to excel sheet in java

Tags: java, json, excel

I am developing an application where I need to export JSON Data to excel sheet. I searched in google . But I didn't get any good tutorial. can you suggest me any tutorial. [this](http://www.danmandle.com/blog/json-to-csv-conversion-utility/) is my exact requirement. But I need the same in Java

Comment: Use a library to parse JSON files (GSON and Jackson are the most well-known), then use a `FileWriter` to write your CSV.

Comment: Apache POI and JExcel can help you.

Comment: You could try to get the PHP source code and manually transform it into java syntax. If the PHP script is short, than this will not be so much of an affort.

Comment: @slartidan can you give me any example. Because I don't know PHP

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Questions on exporting JSON to CSV have been previously asked here and a response was provided here: [Converting JSON to XLS/CSV in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172158/converting-json-to-xls-csv-in-java)

However since you asked for a tutorial [this page](http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-org-json.jsp) shows an example with a different approach.

Hope that helps

Comment: I am getting compliletime error at this line  JSONArray docs = response.getJSONArray("infile"); asking me to create local variable.

Comment: Since I can't see your full code, I'm not sure which local variable you're referring to but it seems like the variable 'response' is the problem... Where did you declare it?

Comment: Hi @pelumi, it seems as of 2023 December, above external link is not available anymore.