# A converter from JSON to CSV in Java doesn't work properly

Tags: java, json, csv

I’m doing a converter from json to csv file. I’ve tried a solution from this link but it doesn’t work properly: [Converting JSON to XLS/CSV in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172158/converting-json-to-xls-csv-in-java)

The problem is that I don’t have data in separate columns and also I have names of columns in different order. Is it possible to fix this?

My json looks like this:

```
{
 "Code":2,
 "Description":"OK",
 "Status":0,
 "Items":[{ "City":"nameOfCity",
        "Country":"nameOfCountry",
        "CountryCode":"US",
        "Latitude":"11.11111",
        "Longitude":"-11.11111",
        "Name":"name of Company",
        "Region":"nameofRegion",
        "ServisID":"111AAA111AA",
        "SiteAddress":"number and street 2301",
        "ZipCode":"1111"},
        {"City":"nameOfCity2",
        "Country":"nameOfCountry",
        "CountryCode":"US",
        "Latitude":"22.22222",
        "Longitude":"22.2222222222",
        "Name":"name of Company2",
        "Region":"nameofRegion",
        "ServisID":"111BBB111BB",
        "SiteAddress":null,
        "ZipCode":null}
        , ...etc.
```

My code:

```
String bodyStr = new String(proxyResponse.getBody());

JSONObject output;

try {
    output = new JSONObject(bodyStr);

    JSONArray docs = output.getJSONArray("Items");

    File file = new File("C:/folder/fromJSON.csv");
    String csv = CDL.toString(docs);
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, csv);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

results(first expected):

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbVkz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working as you expect using the below code. I don't see any major difference between your and my code....

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String inputJson = "{\"Code\":2,\"Description\":\"OK\",\"Status\":0,\"Items\":[{\"City\":\"nameOfCity\",\"Country\":\"nameOfCountry\",\"CountryCode\":\"US\",\"Latitude\":\"11.11111\",\"Longitude\":\"-11.11111\",\"Name\":\"name of Company\",\"Region\":\"nameofRegion\",\"ServisID\":\"111AAA111AA\",\"SiteAddress\":\"number and street 2301\",\"ZipCode\":\"1111\"},{\"City\":\"nameOfCity2\",\"Country\":\"nameOfCountry\",\"CountryCode\":\"US\",\"Latitude\":\"22.22222\",\"Longitude\":\"22.2222222222\",\"Name\":\"name of Company2\",\"Region\":\"nameofRegion\",\"ServisID\":\"111BBB111BB\",\"SiteAddress\":"
                + null + ",\"ZipCode\":" + null + "}]}";
        JSONObject objJsonObject = new JSONObject(inputJson);
        JSONArray objJsonArray = objJsonObject.getJSONArray("Items");
        String csv = CDL.toString(objJsonArray);
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File(System.getenv("HOME")+ "/temp.csv"), csv);
}
```

i opened the csv file using libreoffice v5.1 with UTF-8 encoding

Comment: I've tried libreoffice v5.1 instead of Microsoft Excel and it works but it sets names of columns in different order. It doesn't start from the 'city'.

Comment: And also when I open my file with notepad it has a different form than your input: "SiteAddress,ServisID,ZipCode,Country,Region,Latitude,City,CountryCode,Longitude,Name", maybe that's the problem.