# How to convert jsonarray data to excel in java

Tags: java, arrays, json, rest, apache-poi

Have a requirement where jsonarray data is to be converted and written in an excel file in JAVA. Below is a sample format of the JSON that i receive from the rest api of a marketing tool ActOn:

```
{
"offset":0,
"count":3,
"totalCount":300,
"result":[
{
"a1":a,
"b1":b,
"c1":c
},
{
"a2":a,
"b2":b,
"c2":c
},
{
"a3":a,
"b3":b,
"c3":c
},
.
.
.
.
.
.
,
{
"an":a,
"bn":b,
"cn":c
}
]
```

Comment: Easiest way is to create a csv file which excel can then read

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Take a look into [example](https://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-poi-reading-and-writing-excel-file-in-java/)

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15411074/9085612) answer, maybe it can help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting JSON to XLS/CSV in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172158/converting-json-to-xls-csv-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CSV` format instead of `xml` or `xmls`.
[CSV Format Specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)
So, you don't need any specific libraries and so on.
Just use `\n` to split rows and `,` to split columns.