# Json to csv in below format

Tags: java, json

I am using below code. and with getting this output.

**output**

Header : `{"id" : 12345, "value" : "123", "person" : "1"}`

CDD : `{"CDDid" : 3456 }`

But my required output like this below:

Header id 12345

Header value 123

Header Person 1

CDD CDDid 3456

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Test{

private static HashMap<String, Object> getHashMapFromJson(String json) throws JSONException {
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
    for (Iterator<String> it = jsonObject.keys(); it.hasNext();) {
        String key = it.next();
        map.put(key, jsonObject.get(key));
    }
    return map;
}
   public static void main(String[] args ){

   String json = " { \"Header\" : {\"id\" : 12345, \"value\" : \"123\", \"person\" : \"1\"} ,\"CDD\" : {\"CDDid\" : 3456 }}";
    try {
        HashMap<String, Object> map = getHashMapFromJson(json);
        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(key + ": " + map.get(key));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        System.out.println("JsonTest" + "Failed parsing " + json + e);
    }
   }

   }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172158/converting-json-to-xls-csv-in-java

Comment: that is not what i m looking for i want to print parent name i.e. Header as many as times as child appear

Comment: please guide me with any working solution for above json to get required output

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution where I wanted to get it right already in the `getHashMapFromJson` method.

The toMap method is a simplified version [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24012023/9223839), if your json is more complex you might want to look into implementing the full `toMap` method from that answer and the `toList`method as well.

```
private static HashMap<String, Object> getHashMapFromJson(String json) throws JSONException {
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
    for (Iterator<String> it = jsonObject.keys(); it.hasNext();) {
        String key = it.next();

        JSONObject value = jsonObject.getJSONObject(key);
        Map<String, Object> valueMap = toMap((JSONObject) value);
        valueMap.forEach((k,v) -> map.put(key + " " + k, v));
    }
    return map;
}

public static Map<String, Object> toMap(JSONObject object) throws JSONException {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    Iterator<String> keysItr = object.keys();
    while(keysItr.hasNext()) {
        String key = keysItr.next();
        Object value = object.get(key);

        map.put(key, value);
    }
    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String headerId = json.getJSONObject("Header").getString("id");

String headerValue = json.getJSONObject("Header").getString("value");

String headerperson = json.getJSONObject("Header").getString("person");

String CDDid = json.getJSONObject("CDD").getString("CDDid ");
```

This way to you retrieve json data

Comment: that is working but i do not want to hardcode it is not feasible if have large json

Comment: anyidea without specifying or harcode

Comment: you can use above code in loop

Comment: yes but in method getJSONObject("Header")  i need to specific object that i do not want