# convert json file to excel sheet or csv in java

Tags: java, json, excel

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "address": [
      {
        "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
        "city": "New York",
        "state": "NY",
        "postalCode": "0021"
      }
    ],
    "age": 25,
    "phoneNumbers": [
      {
        "type": "home",
        "number": "212 555-1234"
      },
      {
        "type": "fax",
        "number": "212 555-1234"
      }
    ]
  }
```

take this as an json file and as an input and convert it to the excel sheet..?
i am getting difficulty in parsing the json array.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Maybe you skip the parsing-by-yourself and look for a json-library that does it for you.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172158/converting-json-to-xls-csv-in-java