# getting a JSON-response from API and map it with POJO-class using Mule

Tags: java, json, mule

I would have to get a JSONArray from URL and convert the received data to a .csv -file. I'm rather new with Java and Mule. We are using Community Edition of the Mule, so the transform message -component isn't an option here.

I have created a POJO-class "JsonData" with all the getters and setters and I understood that using that POJO-class as a return class of the JSON-to-Object -transformer in Mule would match the JSON-property names to the ones in that POJO-class.

Here is my JSON data:

```
[
{
    "accountId": "064418ca1d292a5112e9804af4dc66df5b90203c",
    "iban": "FI2350009421535899",
    "bic": "OKOYFIHH",
    "accountName": "KÄYTTÖTILI",
    "balance": 0,
    "amountAvailable": 0,
    "currency": "EUR"
},
{
    "accountId": "07618ad83d7c5d5f2db8908d33b6a9272c5e8d96",
    "iban": "FI7858400761900714",
    "bic": "OKOYFIHH",
    "accountName": "KASVUTUOTTO",
    "balance": 3137.57,
    "amountAvailable": 3137.57,
    "currency": "EUR"
}
]
```

And here is my POJO-class generated by the jsonschema2pojo.org -tool:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"accountId",
"iban",
"bic",
"accountName",
"balance",
"amountAvailable",
"currency"
})

public class JsonData {


@JsonProperty("accountId")
private String accountId;
@JsonProperty("iban")
private String iban;
@JsonProperty("bic")
private String bic;
@JsonProperty("accountName")
private String accountName;
@JsonProperty("balance")
private Double balance;
@JsonProperty("amountAvailable")
private Double amountAvailable;
@JsonProperty("currency")
private String currency;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

@JsonProperty("accountId")
public String getAccountId() {
return accountId;
}

@JsonProperty("accountId")
public void setAccountId(String accountId) {
this.accountId = accountId;
}

@JsonProperty("iban")
public String getIban() {
return iban;
}

@JsonProperty("iban")
public void setIban(String iban) {
this.iban = iban;
}

@JsonProperty("bic")
public String getBic() {
return bic;
}

@JsonProperty("bic")
public void setBic(String bic) {
this.bic = bic;
}

@JsonProperty("accountName")
public String getAccountName() {
return accountName;
}

@JsonProperty("accountName")
public void setAccountName(String accountName) {
this.accountName = accountName;
}

@JsonProperty("balance")
public Double getBalance() {
return balance;
}

@JsonProperty("balance")
public void setBalance(Double balance) {
this.balance = balance;
}

@JsonProperty("amountAvailable")
public Double getAmountAvailable() {
return amountAvailable;
}

@JsonProperty("amountAvailable")
public void setAmountAvailable(Double amountAvailable) {
this.amountAvailable = amountAvailable;
}

@JsonProperty("currency")
public String getCurrency() {
return currency;
}

@JsonProperty("currency")
public void setCurrency(String currency) {
this.currency = currency;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}
}
```

I also have a Mule flow with GET-request, Json-To-Object -transformer, Object-To-String -transformer, logger-component and File-endpoint which writes the log or the payload to a new text file. The problem is that when I run the Mule flow, the payload isn't the one it should be... below is my Mule Flow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" 
xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" 
xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" 
xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" 
xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd">
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" protocol="HTTPS" 
host="sandbox.apis.op-palvelut.fi" port="443" doc:name="HTTP Request 
Configuration"/>
<file:connector name="CreateFile" autoDelete="true" streaming="true" 
validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
<file:endpoint path="${juuri.csv}" name="CreateCSV" responseTimeout="10000" 
doc:name="File"/>
<file:endpoint path="${juuri.log}" name="CreateLog" responseTimeout="10000" 
doc:name="File"/>
<flow name="myynnittonovaFlow">
    <poll doc:name="Poll">
        <fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="5" timeUnit="SECONDS"/>
        <logger message="Started....." level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </poll>
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="v1/accounts" 
method="GET" doc:name="HTTP">
        <http:request-builder>
            <http:header headerName="x-authorization" value="${auth}"/>
            <http:header headerName="x-api-key" value="${api_key}"/>
        </http:request-builder>
    </http:request>
    <json:json-to-object-transformer 
returnClass="json.csv.testing.JsonData[]" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <file:outbound-endpoint outputPattern="log.txt" connector- 
ref="CreateFile" ref="CreateLog"  responseTimeout="10000" 
doc:name="CreateLog"/>
  </flow>
</mule>
```

And the payload I am getting from that is:

```
{json.csv.testing.JsonData@22fddfa0,json.csv.testing.JsonData@34ff4054}
```

So am I missing something here or what could be the issue? I hope that I explained this correctly...

UPDATE:

I modified my POJO-class by adding a toString() and I was able to get the actual payloads now. My second challenge is to convert that payload to CSV using a custom method I have made.

Here is my modified POJO-class:

```
public class JsonData {


@JsonProperty("accountId")
private String accountId;
@JsonProperty("iban")
private String iban;
@JsonProperty("bic")
private String bic;
@JsonProperty("accountName")
private String accountName;
@JsonProperty("balance")
private Double balance;
@JsonProperty("amountAvailable")
private Double amountAvailable;
@JsonProperty("currency")
private String currency;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, 
Object>();

@JsonProperty("accountId")
public String getAccountId() {
return accountId;
}

@JsonProperty("accountId")
public void setAccountId(String accountId) {
this.accountId = accountId;
}

@JsonProperty("iban")
public String getIban() {
return iban;
}

@JsonProperty("iban")
public void setIban(String iban) {
this.iban = iban;
}

@JsonProperty("bic")
public String getBic() {
return bic;
}

@JsonProperty("bic")
public void setBic(String bic) {
this.bic = bic;
}

@JsonProperty("accountName")
public String getAccountName() {
return accountName;
}

@JsonProperty("accountName")
public void setAccountName(String accountName) {
this.accountName = accountName;
}

@JsonProperty("balance")
public Double getBalance() {
return balance;
}

@JsonProperty("balance")
public void setBalance(Double balance) {
this.balance = balance;
}

@JsonProperty("amountAvailable")
public Double getAmountAvailable() {
return amountAvailable;
}

@JsonProperty("amountAvailable")
public void setAmountAvailable(Double amountAvailable) {
this.amountAvailable = amountAvailable;
}

@JsonProperty("currency")
public String getCurrency() {
return currency;
}

@JsonProperty("currency")
public void setCurrency(String currency) {
this.currency = currency;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

@Override
public String toString() {

  return "accountId: " +  getAccountId() + " iban: " + getIban() + " bic: " 
+ getBic() + " accountName: " + getAccountName() + " balance: " + 
getBalance() 
+ " amountAvailable: " + getAmountAvailable() + " currency: " + 
getCurrency() + "\r\n"; 
}
}
```

And here is the class which should do the conversion to CSV....

```
public class DataToCSV {
public static final String HEADER = 
"CODE;IBAN;BIC;NAME;BALANCE;AMOUNTAVAILABLE;CURRENCY";

public static String doCSV(Vector<JsonData> json) throws Exception {
    String str = new String();
    Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonData[] data = gson.fromJson(json.toString(), JsonData[].class);

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        try {
       values.clear();
       values.put("CODE", data[i].getAccountId());
       values.put("IBAN", data[i].getIban());
       values.put("BIC", data[i].getBic());
       values.put("NAME", data[i].getAccountName());
       values.put("BALANCE", Double.toString(data[i].getBalance()));   
values.put("AMOUNTAVAILABLE",Double.toString(data[i].getAmountAvailable()));
       values.put("CURRENCY", data[i].getCurrency());
       str=str.concat(NovaUtils.doNovaLine(values,HEADER.split(";")));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    if (str != null && !str.isEmpty()) {
        str = HEADER + "\r\n" + str;
    }

    return str;
}


}
```

So I have couple of questions actually here; One is that does the doCsv() look ok and if I want to test that out, what are the parameters to assign for the method?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's doing exactly what you've asked of it. Since your payload has two json objects, you're getting an array of two JsonData Objects.

If you want to log the actual payloads, try this:

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="JsonData" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
<foreach collection="#[payload]" doc:name="For Each">
    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</foreach>
```

You may need a toString() in your POJO.

UPDATE:
I would refer you to [Converting JSON to XLS/CSV in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172158/converting-json-to-xls-csv-in-java)

Comment: I was able to get the actual payload just by adding a toString() to my POJO-class. I will update my question, since I do have another question.