# How to download firebase data base as a CSV file from android

Tags: android, json, firebase, csv, firebase-realtime-database

There is a requirement for download the database data as a `.CSV` file. How can I get data from Firebase realtime database and convert it to `.CSV` format in Android?

Firebase only gave manual download database in `JSON` format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for button that allows you download your database in another format than `JSON`, there isnt't one. To solve you should do your yourself. So according to your database schema, you should write custom code that will help you convert a `JSON` file to a `CSV` file. A possile solution might be, Sridhar's answer from the following post:

- [Converting JSON to XLS/CSV in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172158/converting-json-to-xls-csv-in-java)

Comment: But the 1st problem is cannot get json file from firebase, Is there any way to download json from firebase

Comment: Yes, you can do that directly from the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/). Select your project -> Select Database -> Select **Realtime Database** -> Click on the three dots -> Export JSON. Does it work now?

Comment: thanks, but I need to download it via my android application. That is the actual problem.

Comment: In that case, you need to iterate over your entire database according to your database schema. Check the official documentation regarding [retrieving data in Firebase realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data). Once you have that data, convert it to a `CSV` file and write locally, that's it.