# How to convert json file to excel file in java

Tags: java, json, excel

I,m given a problem to convert `JSON` file to excel file, in short to convert `JSON` data to excel data. Tried mapping `JSON` keys and values but can't do it.

Tried mapping `JSON` keys and values but can't do it. I have already used apache POI api.

```
public class jsontoexcel {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,JSONException {
        jsontoexcel json4=new jsontoexcel();
        JSONObject json=json4.ReadJson();
        JSONArray array =new JSONArray();
        JSONObject rowjson=json.getJSONArray("rows").getJSONObject(0);

        XSSFWorkbook workbook=new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet=workbook.createSheet("Company Details");

        int len=rowjson.length();
        String[] RowArr=new String[len];
        Iterator<String> keys = rowjson.keys();
        int i=0;
        while(keys.hasNext())
        {
            RowArr[i]=keys.next();
            System.out.print("key:"+keys);
            i++;
        }
        List<String> slist= new ArrayList<String>();
        slist=json.get(rowjson.toString(keys));

         FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\code\\eclipse\\jsontoexcel\\src\\output.xlsx"));

         createHeaderRow(sheet, RowArr);
         workbook.write(out);
         out.close();



      //  Map<String,Object> map=new Map<String,Object>();      

    }

    public static void createHeaderRow(XSSFSheet sheet, String[] RowArr)
    {
        Row row=sheet.createRow(0);
        for(int i=0;i<RowArr.length-1;i++)
        {
            Cell cellTitle=row.createCell(i+1);
            String cellVal=RowArr[i];
            System.out.print("Cell data" + cellVal);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be stored in an excel file. The headers are getting printed but not the values.

Comment: I think your question already has an answer
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172158/converting-json-to-xls-csv-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172158/converting-json-to-xls-csv-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not generate `Excel` file until you really have to. In case, you want to generate data without any specific formatting, charts, macros, etc. just generate `CSV` file with pure data. To read `JSON` and generate `CSV` you can use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core) library which supports these two data formats. Just assume your `JSON` looks like below:

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Vika",
      "age": 27
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Mike",
      "age": 28
    }
  ]
}
```

You, need to create `POJO` model which fits to that structure, deserialise `JSON` to objects and serialise objects to `CSV` format. Example solution, could look like below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SequenceWriter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvSchema;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Response response = jsonMapper.readValue(jsonFile, Response.class);

        CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
        CsvSchema schema = csvMapper.schemaFor(Item.class).withHeader();
        SequenceWriter sequenceWriter = csvMapper.writer(schema).writeValues(System.out);
        sequenceWriter.writeAll(response.getRows());
    }
}

class Response {
    private List<Item> rows;

    // getters, setters
}

@JsonPropertyOrder({"id", "name", "age"})
class Item {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    // getters, setters
}
```

Above code prints:

```
id,name,age
1,Vika,27
2,Mike,28
```

See also:

- [jackson-dataformats-text](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/tree/master/csv)
- [Intro to the Jackson ObjectMapper](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial)