# How to create a standalone application to convert JSON file data to Excel by using java

Tags: java, json, excel, spring, spring-boot

I'm new to IT Industry and My lead gave a Task to convert JSON file which contains JSON arrays, objects and Nested with 4000 lines to convert into Excel sheet in locally by reading JSON file. Please help me fellow coders.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172158/converting-json-to-xls-csv-in-java) is could be helpful. Best Regards

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck 

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot to unpack here.
You are asking for instructions to build a Java Application without providing much context regarding the entire use case. There are a lot of different ways to approach your problem.
If you are new to Spring-Boot, I'd suggest reading the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/).

It hopefully will provide you with a basic understanding of the core concepts.

Now lets get to the JSON-to-XLS conversion. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172158/converting-json-to-xls-csv-in-java) question, it is recommended to convert your JSON-Data into the CSV format. CSV could be interpreted as an open alternative to xls for tabular data. As far as I'm aware, Excel can open CSV files.