# How do i get values from json?

Tags: android, json, assets, language-translation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [convert csv/xls to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662859/convert-csv-xls-to-json)

I have in my assets an excel sheet showing 2 language translation. i want to convert the excel sheet values in a json format. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a possible solution. I hope that it will help you.
Let assume that you have following table:

```
           A              B                C                 D
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    Hello               Translat1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2    Bye                 Translat2   
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3    World               Translat3
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4    How are you         Translat4     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In C1 copy and paste the following formula:

> =""""&"data"&""""&":["&"{"&""""&"english"&""""&":"&""""&A1&""""&"},{"&""""&"other"&""""&":"&""""&B1&""""&"}"&"]"

After this, copy/paste this formula through all cells of column C. The column C should look like:

```
                   C
----------------------------------------------------
"data":[{"english":"Hello"},{"other":"Translat1"}]
"data":[{"english":"Bye"},{"other":"Translat2"}]
"data":[{"english":"How are you"},{"other":"Translat3"}]
"data":[{"english":"World"},{"other":"Translat4"}]
```

In cell D2 copy/paste this formula:

> =C1&","&C2

In D3 copy/paste this formula

> =D2&","&C3

The last formula from D3 should be copied in coming cells. In our case the output should look like

```
"data":[{"english":"Hello"},{"other":"Translat1"}],"data":[{"english":"Bye"},{"other":"Translat2"}],"data":[{"english":"How are you"},{"other":"Translat3"}],"data":[{"english":"World"},{"other":"Translat4"}]
```

In order the last result to be valid json you have add { at the begging and } at the end.
This is not proved solution for many records.