# Parse response using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have to parse a response from the server,
        The response is like..

```
[4,"1.0",1368544417760]
[1,"Great West Road","222",1368544595000]
[1,"Ruislip Manor Station","114",1368544479000]
[1,"Bank Station  / Threadneedle Street","26",1368544731000]
[1,"Belvue School","E10",1368545955000]
[1,"Brunel Road","283",1368544706000]
[1,"Annesley Avenue","303",1368545930000]
[1,"Brixton Station Road","35",1368545854000]
[1,"Southampton Row","91",1368545537000]
[1,"Camden Road Station","29",1368545008000]
[1,"Fulham Cemetery","74",1368545210000]
```

The response doesn't seem to like JSON or XML.
Please help me know how to parse such type of response using Jquery.
I have to update the DOM based on the response and the response is getting updated
at a regular interval automatically.

Comment: Is this one response or multiple responses?

Comment: it is indeed not json nor xml, rather some kind of csv. You will need to write some code then come back here with a specific problem, SO isn't a place where you ask others to write code for you...

Comment: Why don't you replace linefeeds by commas and surround the whole thing with brackets so you have JSON ?

Comment: @Bartdude I am not asking anyone to write code for me, I am new to JS so I asked is there any way to parse such kind of response..

Comment: @RocketHazmat This is one response , this is kind of live feed..

Comment: @LeeMeador that should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: there are lots of ways to parse just about anything, but without seeing any of the code you've tried it's difficult to help you. you've already gotten a few good suggestions for changing the response itself to something more easily parseable in javascript - json.

Comment: @user1589459 : sorry then. Here's an answer : YES, there are many ways.

Answer (score 1):

The first number may be an indicator of what sort of data is in the rest of the "array".

I'd say

1. parse each line as if it were JSON. It'll turn into a javascript array.

   ```
   var array = JSON.parse(oneLine); // Many browsers support this.
   ```
2. Then pull the bits out and put them into a proper object by name. (How to do that depends on the 1st element, perhaps.)

   ```
   var obj = {};
   if (array[0] == 1) {
       obj.station = obj[1];
       obj.number = obj[2];
       obj.timestamp = obj[3]; // guessing what this is, too.
   }
   ```
3. Do whatever you need with the data object.

Put all that in a loop. Repeat until done.

Comment: To format code in a list, prefix it with 8 spaces (instead of 4) ^_^

Comment: @RocketHazmat Got it. It's in a list, so it has to be formatted with more indentation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar Stack Overflow question here -->  [converting CSV/XLS to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662859/converting-csv-xls-to-json)

Looks like there are a few different possible solutions that you could look at.