# Convert Excel .xls to .csv, .xml or JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, excel, csv, google-apps-script

Using `Javascript`, specifically `Google Apps Script` (GAS), I need to convert an `.xls` file to `JSON`; but I would settle for `.csv` or `.xml`.

Does anyone know any way to do this? Some library, perhaps? Or a private script willing to share? (Note: GAS can not recognize `ActiveXObject`)

#### Prior research (does not apply)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662859/converting-csv-xls-to-json) question does not apply because I am asking for a solution coded in Javascript (or a workaround for Google Apps Script). (The answers to the above question focus on a Java solution and other various .csv to JSON converters.)

Yes, I know there is an open [issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1019) for GAS already in the works. But I was wondering if anyone has coded any .js workaround to do the job in the meantime?

Comment: Isn't `xls` a proprietary Microsoft format?

Comment: No, wait. That other question does not do. The critical difference is that .01%. I am asking for a solution coded in Javascript (or a workaround for Google Apps Script). Yes, I know there is an open issue for GAS already in the works. But I was wondering if anyone has coded a .js workaround to do the job in the meantime? Note: My original question has been edited accordingly to reflect this.

Comment: Probably too late @HappyLearner but check out http://niggler.github.io/js-xls/

Comment: For a GAS example, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27281814/1677912) by @SergeInsas, especially `function importXLS()`.