# How to convert a Google Sheets-File to an Excel-File (XLSX)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, xlsx, urlfetch

The image shows the code who is updated.
[image: 1]

The var "xlsFile" is undefined, why? How can I convert the Google Sheets file to an Excel file with (Google Sheets) Script Editor

```js
function googleOAuth_ (name, scope) {
   var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
   oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?     scope="+scope);
   oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
   oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
   oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey('anonymous');
   oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret('anonymous');
   return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always"};
}

function test(){
  var id = '#'
  exportToXls(id)
}

function exportToXls(id){
   var mute =  {muteHttpExceptions: true };
   var name = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getName()
   var url = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/';
   var doc = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+'download/spreadsheets/Export?key='+id+'&exportFormat=xls',     mute).getBlob()
   var xlsfile = DocsList.createFile(doc).rename(name+'.xlsx')
}
```

Comment: The MIME type to convert to. For most blobs, 'application/pdf' is the only valid option. This MIME type (Excel) is not supported with getAs(). You can find more information on this link: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/file

Comment: Here's a similar question with an up-to-date answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31809987/google-app-scripts-email-a-spreadsheet-as-excel

Answer (score 11):

Using the Drive API, we can get more information about files than is available through the DriveApp methods. Check out the [file data](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files), especially `exportLinks`. Those links contain the magic that will let us get an XLS file. (For fun, put a breakpoint after `file` is assigned, and check what information you have to play with.)

This script uses the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive), which [must be enabled](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services). A more complete version, with error checking, is available in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mogsdad/7977853f69fd7cdc8fa0).

```js
/**
 * Downloads spreadsheet with given file id as an Excel file.
 * Uses Advanced Drive Service, which must be enabled. * Throws if error encountered.
 *
 * @param {String}   fileId       File ID of Sheets file on Drive.
 */
function downloadXLS(fileId) {
  var file = Drive.Files.get(fileId);
  var url = file.exportLinks[MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL];

  var options = {
    headers: {
      Authorization:"Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    },
    muteHttpExceptions : true        /// Get failure results
  }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var status = response.getResponseCode();
  var result = response.getContentText();
  if (status != 200) {
    // Get additional error message info, depending on format
    if (result.toUpperCase().indexOf("<HTML") !== -1) {
      var message = strip_tags(result);
    }
    else if (result.indexOf('errors') != -1) {
      message = JSON.parse(result).error.message;
    }
    throw new Error('Error (' + status + ") " + message );
  }

  var doc = response.getBlob();
  //DocsList.createFile(doc).rename(file.title + '.xlsx') // Deprecated
  DriveApp.createFile(doc).setName(file.title + '.xlsx');
}
```

Comment: Mogsdad, I think the UrlFetch needs a token to download the converted file. Please take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32356863/converting-google-spreadsheet-to-excel-with-appscript-and-send-it-via-email/32359156#32359156)

Comment: Thanks @HenriqueAbreu. Fully updated with my production script.

Answer (score 2):

*The code below uses oAuthConfig which is now deprecated. Use Mogsdad answer instead. The importXLS function uses the drive API and still works.*

---

You'll find many post saying this is not possible and (a few) others saying that you can...and obviously you can !

Mogsdad's answer here (simultaneously) brings an elegant solution using drive service, here is another one so you have a choice ;-)

As a bonus, I added the reverse process, if ever you need it.

Use a function call similar to what I use in the test function to make it work.

```
function googleOAuth_(name,scope) {
  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
  oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey('anonymous');
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret('anonymous');
  return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always"};
}

function test(){
  var id = 'spreadsheet_ID'
  exportToXls(id)
}

function exportToXls(id){
  var name = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getName()
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/';
  var doc = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+'download/spreadsheets/Export?key='+id+'&exportFormat=xls',
                              googleOAuth_('docs',url)).getBlob()
  var xlsfile = DocsList.createFile(doc).rename(name+'.xls')
}

function importXLS(){
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains ".xls"');
  while(files.hasNext()){
    var xFile = files.next();
    var name = xFile.getName();
    if (name.indexOf('.xls')>-1){
      var ID = xFile.getId();
      var xBlob = xFile.getBlob();
      var newFile = { title : name+'_converted',
                     key : ID
                    }
      file = Drive.Files.insert(newFile, xBlob, {
        convert: true
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Beat you by 5 minutes!

Comment: you're just typing faster XD

Comment: The error that comes when I run the query. </br>
<pre>Fehler bei der Anfrage für . Folgender Code wurde zurückgegeben: 404. Gekürzte Serverantwort: <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="de" ><head><meta name="description" content="Textverarbeitung, Präsentationen und Tabellen im Web"><link rel="shortcut i.... Verwenden Sie "muteHttpExceptions", um die vollständige Antwort zu lesen. (Zeile 19, Datei "Code")</pre>

Comment: how are you trying this code ? did you follow exactly the procedure I described ?

Comment: I've updated my Code (see above),  and it still happens nothing? @Sergeinsas

Comment: @Mogsdad whats your meaning?

Comment: @dave872 - I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @Mogsdad with a successful run of the code, the file must be created or not?

Comment: I just want a Google Docs file saved as an Excel file , is this so difficult? @Mogsdad

Comment: @dave872 - It only seems difficult because you have implemented it wrong. The updated code in your question shows that you left out the Authorization bearer from the `options` parameter, and are instead only muting exceptions. You must provide that authorization, otherwise `UrlFetchApp` will be like a user who has not logged in, it will have no access to Google Drive. (Why are you asking me about Serge's answer, anyway? Did you even try mine?)

Comment: When I implement the Authorization then comes this Error:
Methode fetch(string,object,object) nicht gefunden (Zeile 33, Datei "Export") @Mogsdad

Comment: And when I implement the code without the mute (mutehttpExceptions) then come the Server Error (see above)   ||

var doc = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+'download/spreadsheets/Export?key='+id+'&exportFormat=xlsx', googleOAuth_('docs',url)).getBlob() @Mogsdad

Comment: ` fetch(string,object,object)` - there are just TWO parameters for fetch - you're doing it wrong.