# Create excel document from google spreadsheet row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the code found here:
[How to convert a Google Docs-File to an Excel-File (XLSX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277058/how-to-convert-a-google-docs-file-to-an-excel-file-xlsx) and more specifically [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/mogsdad/7977853f69fd7cdc8fa0) to create an excel file.

I need to modify the code.

1. Create an excel file each time a new row is added to the google
   spreadsheet. **Working now**
2. The new excel file row 1 should be the headers from the source spreadsheet and row 2 should be the new row that was added to the
   source spreadsheet.
3. The name of the file should be based upon the values found in the new row, columns 2 & 15. **Working Now**
4. The new excel file should be placed in folder "Form Responses" id= 0B-eAmBjlnU16YTJIVVFpMjJoTzQ. **Working Now**

I was able to modify the code to trigger when a new row was added, to use the values from the last row, columns 2 & 15 as the name of the file and move the newly created file to a specific folder (steps 1, 3 & 4) but am stuck on step 2. The function works when manually run its just not triggering when I would expect it to (On spreadsheet change, edit or form submit)

```
      function test_downloadXLS() {
  var fileId = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID").getId();
  downloadXLS( fileId);
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A2:DI2');

  var files = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B-eAmBjlnU16YTJIVVFpMjJoTzQ");
    destination.addFile(file);
    var pull = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
    pull.removeFile(file);
    range.clear()
  }
 }

/**
 * Downloads spreadsheet with given file id as an Excel file.
 * Uses Advanced Drive Service, which must be enabled.
 * Throws if error encountered.
 *
 * From https://stackoverflow.com/a/27281729/1677912
 *
 * @param {String}   fileId       File ID of Sheets file on Drive.
 */
function downloadXLS(fileId) {
  var file = Drive.Files.get(fileId);
  var url = file.exportLinks[MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL];

 var options = {
   headers: {
     Authorization:"Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
   },
    muteHttpExceptions : true        /// Get failure results
  }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var status = response.getResponseCode();
  var result = response.getContentText();
  if (status != 200) {
    // Get additional error message info, depending on format
    if (result.toUpperCase().indexOf("<HTML") !== -1) {
      var message = strip_tags(result);
    }
    else if (result.indexOf('errors') != -1) {
      message = JSON.parse(result).error.message;
    }
    throw new Error('Error (' + status + ") " + message );
  }

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('16Vv_FqrZyeCmCoK9XAvujVRisa-5m3FabH5uNAKprYc');
  var sh = ss.getSheets()[0];// access first sheet (0 indexed)
  var row = sh.getLastRow();
  var data = sh.getRange(row, 2).getValue();
   var row2 = sh.getLastRow();
  var data2 = sh.getRange(row, 15).getValue();

  var doc = response.getBlob();
  DriveApp.createFile(doc).setName(data + "-" + data2 + '.xlsx');
}


// A JavaScript equivalent of PHP’s strip_tags
// from http://phpjs.org/functions/strip_tags/
function strip_tags(input, allowed) {
  allowed = (((allowed || '') + '')
    .toLowerCase()
    .match(/<[a-z][a-z0-9]*>/g) || [])
    .join(''); // making sure the allowed arg is a string containing only tags in lowercase (<a><b><c>)
  var tags = /<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>/gi,
    commentsAndPhpTags = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->|<\?(?:php)?[\s\S]*?\?>/gi;
  return input.replace(commentsAndPhpTags, '')
    .replace(tags, function($0, $1) {
      return allowed.indexOf('<' + $1.toLowerCase() + '>') > -1 ? $0 : '';
    });
}
```

I didn't have much luck finding information on how to export only a specific range as an excel file (Step 2) so I tried a different approach with some success but ran into another problem.

I created a second spreadsheet which has the same headers as the first. In the first spreadsheet I use the following code to copy a new row to this new spreadsheet:

```
  function initializeTrigger()
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
   .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
   .onChange()
   .create();
}
function myFunction(e){
  Logger.log(e.changeType);
  if(e.changeType=='INSERT_ROW'){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID');
  var ssd = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID');
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Responses');
  var lastrow = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange(lastrow, 1, 1, 53).getValues();
ssd.appendRow(sourceData[0]);
}
}
```

In the new spreadsheet, the second one, I tried the original code seen at the beginning of this post but it's not working. I think the problem here might be the fact that I'm adding a row, exporting it and then deleting the row so the next time a new row is copied over the log is not seeing anything new in terms of new rows?

I also tried the code referenced here [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/mogsdad/7977853f69fd7cdc8fa0) and it works when run manually but I can't figure out a trigger which would work as soon as the new row is copied over.

Comment: to make a valid question, do show us your attempts. so far you dont seem to have attempted coding. look at SpreadsheetApp documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have added a few more details

Comment: I have 3 of the 4 steps now working. Step two is probably the most difficult...

Comment: which part of the code is step 2, and what isnt working?

Comment: I couldn't find many details on converting only a specific range to an excel document so I tried a different approach. see above edits

Answer (score 0):

So all I had to do was put all of the code into one script file to be triggered all at once. Might not be the most efficient or pretty way to do this but it works for what I need it to do. One problem is that if new rows are added simultaneously the naming and creation of the excel file will have problems.

Summary:
This script will do the following

1. Move new rows from one spreadsheet to a second spreadsheet with only
   headers
2. Create an excel file based upon the second spreadsheet
3. Move the excel file to a specific folder
4. Delete the row that was created in the second spreadsheet in anticipation of the next new row

Manualy run the initializeTrigger first. The trigger should be set to "on change".

```
function initializeTrigger(){ // run this only once to create a trigger if necessary
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
  .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
  .onChange()
  .create();
}

function myFunction(e){
  Logger.log(e.changeType);
  if(e.changeType=='INSERT_ROW'){ // do Something

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Spreadsheet ID'); //Project database and source data sheet #1
  var ssd = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Spreadsheet ID'); //Spreadsheet to be converted into excel document
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Responses'); 
  var lastrow = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange(lastrow, 1, 1, 113).getValues();
  ssd.appendRow(sourceData[0]);
  var fileId = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Spreadsheet ID").getId(); //Spreadsheet to be converted into excel document
  downloadXLS( fileId);
  var files = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("Folder ID"); // Folder where exported excel files are moved too
    destination.addFile(file);
    var pull = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
    pull.removeFile(file);
    ssd.deleteRow(2)
}
}

 /**
 * Downloads spreadsheet with given file id as an Excel file.
 * Uses Advanced Drive Service, which must be enabled.
 * Throws if error encountered.
 *
 * From http://stackoverflow.com/a/27281729/1677912
 *
 * @param {String}   fileId       File ID of Sheets file on Drive.
 */
function downloadXLS(fileId) {
  var file = Drive.Files.get(fileId);
  var url = file.exportLinks[MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL];

 var options = {
   headers: {
     Authorization:"Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
   },
    muteHttpExceptions : true        /// Get failure results
  }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var status = response.getResponseCode();
  var result = response.getContentText();
  if (status != 200) {
    // Get additional error message info, depending on format
    if (result.toUpperCase().indexOf("<HTML") !== -1) {
      var message = strip_tags(result);
    }
    else if (result.indexOf('errors') != -1) {
      message = JSON.parse(result).error.message;
    }
    throw new Error('Error (' + status + ") " + message );
  }

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Spreadsheet ID');
  var sh = ss.getSheets()[0];// access first sheet (0 indexed)
  var row = sh.getLastRow();
  var data = sh.getRange(row, 2).getValue();
  var row2 = sh.getLastRow();
  var data2 = sh.getRange(row, 15).getValue();
  var doc = response.getBlob();
  DriveApp.createFile(doc).setName(data + "-" + data2 + '.xlsx').setDescription(data + "-" + data2);
}


// A JavaScript equivalent of PHP’s strip_tags
// from http://phpjs.org/functions/strip_tags/
function strip_tags(input, allowed) {
  allowed = (((allowed || '') + '')
    .toLowerCase()
    .match(/<[a-z][a-z0-9]*>/g) || [])
    .join(''); // making sure the allowed arg is a string containing only tags in lowercase (<a><b><c>)
  var tags = /<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>/gi,
    commentsAndPhpTags = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->|<\?(?:php)?[\s\S]*?\?>/gi;
  return input.replace(commentsAndPhpTags, '')
    .replace(tags, function($0, $1) {
      return allowed.indexOf('<' + $1.toLowerCase() + '>') > -1 ? $0 : '';
    });
}
}
```