# How to send a Google Sheet as an email attachment?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, gmail-api

I am currently trying to send a Google Sheet as an email attachment using Google Apps Script. When I execute the code (shown below) it automatically sends it as a PDF even though I have not specified I want to send it in this format.

Is there a way to send the attachment in the Google Sheets format?

```js
function emailGoogleSheet()
{
    try
    {
      // Get file from Google Drive
      var googleSheet = DriveApp.getFileById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
      
      // Send email with file attached
      MailApp.sendEmail("name@email.co.uk", "Report", "Please see the attached report.", {attachments: googleSheet})
    }
    catch (exception)
    {
        Logger.log(exception);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- The documentation for [attachment](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-attachment) specifies:

> This is a regular Blob

- And the documentation about the [contentType for blobs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getascontenttype) says:

> contentType
>
> The MIME type to convert to. For most blobs, 'application/pdf' is the
> only valid option.

### There are two things you can do

- If you want to send your Google spreadsheet as a spreadsheet - you need to send the link to the file in the message body, rather than adding the file as attachment
- If you want to send the file as a different file format (e.g. xls) - you will need to convert it to such beforehand, manually - e.g. as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60759727/exporting-google-sheet-as-xlxs-and-renaming/60760831#60760831)

Comment: Thanks for the response ziganotschka. This is for a business application and the business is google dependant so I will need to use option one which will link the google sheet in the email.

Answer (score 0):

the following code will do the work

```
const file = DriveApp.getFileById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

GmailApp.sendEmail(
    'email',
    'subject',
    new_emailbody,
    {
      htmlBody: new_emailbody,
      attachments: [file]
    });
```