# Sencha touch 2 basic data load from json?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Hi I am new for sencha touch .I want to play with json proxy but i have several questions.

I have data in excel file. how to load this data to sencha touch(how to convert this as json url link?). Also if i want to query the retrieved data, is that possible in sencha 2?

Thanks & Regards
Sankar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [converting CSV/XLS to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662859/converting-csv-xls-to-json) to export your excel data to json.

Then you just need to define a model, store and proxy to read your data into your sencha touch app (look into the sencha touch doc, model and store are quite easy to implement).

The proxy is not really difficult but depend on how and where you will host your json data. The following example shows the code if you host the json file on your localhost server: 
http://training.figleaf.com/tutorials/senchacomplete/chapter2/lesson6/2.cfm