# CSV to JSON Formatting

Tags: json, excel, csv

I have a CSV which looks like this:

[image: CSV]

When I convert it to JSON I get this:

```
{
 "Thing1": "Value1",
 "Thing2": "Value2",
 "Thing3": 2209,
 "": 2210,
 ... etc

}
```

What I want is for it to look like this:

```
{
 "Thing1": "Value1",
 "Thing2": "Value2",
 "Thing3": { 
   2209,
   2210,
   2210,
   ... etc
 }
}
```

Do I need to write a script to make this? Thanks

Comment: Yes you have to write a script.

Comment: You've told us nothing about your environment? Is this an "export from excel to json" question?

Comment: Yes thats correct @mortb

Comment: added excel tag

Comment: This question might get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662859/converting-csv-xls-to-json

Answer (score 1):

Basically, in your example, what you are looking for is to wrap a cross table into a normal json array.

I created a tiny free app at [csvtojson.com](http://csvtojson.com) that is able to convert your csv to json while allowing you to declare a nesting structure.

Following with your example, you just need to specify your output structure in your CSV header as follow:

```
Thing 1, Thing 2, Thing 3.0, Thing 3.1, Thing 3.2, Thing 3.3, Thing 3.4
Value 1, Value 2, 2209, 2210, 2211, 2212, 2213, 2214
```

Put this csv into the app and press the "Convert !" button. It will understand that `Thing 3.1` is actually the second element of the array `Thing 3` : exactly what you asked for.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

"Thing3" should be array, then you can make well json object. it is like this

```
"Thing3": [] {"2209","2210"}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some tools you can try without writing code, for example [this popped up](http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm) on a quick Google search.  It claims that **it supports conversion to JSON arrays** which you'll need for your example (Thing3 should probably be an array) - **caveat: I haven't tried it.**

As you can imagine, most answers from Stackers will involve some form of programming. If you want to delve deeper there's a good example in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662859/converting-csv-xls-to-json).

Last point, your example isn't strictly CSV. Perhaps you meant that the source CSV was like:

Thing1, Thing2, Thing3, Thing3, Thing3
Value1, Value2, 2209, 2210, 2211

Good luck!